# How to check array element greater than specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison-operators

I have the following array, and I need to check if the array any `AvgWT` value

1. is greater than 15000 and less than 20000 then return 50
2. is greater than 10000 and less than 15000 then return 100
3. is greater than 5000 and less than 10000 then return 150

I tried following code.

```
var arry = [{"TimeSlot":"8:00 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":12152},{"TimeSlot":"8:15 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":13942},{"TimeSlot":"8:30 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"8:45 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"9:00 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"9:15 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"6:30 pm","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"6:45 pm","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"7:00 pm","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0}];

function isArrayValueGreater(arry) {
   // var first = array[0];
    var first = arry[0]["AvgWaitTime"];
    return arry.every(function(element) {
        if(element["AvgWaitTime"]> 15000 &&  element["AvgWaitTime"]< 20000){
            return 50;
        }else if(element["AvgWaitTime"]> 10000 && element["AvgWaitTime"]<15000){
            return 100;
        }
    });
}

isValuesSameG = isArrayValueGreater(arry);
```

But its not working properly, What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Your code and the expected result don't make any sense. If you want to check `isArrayValueGreater` then why you want to return values?? Also, `every` method returns a Boolean value, so return 50, 100 makes no sense.

Comment: What is the expected return value of isArrayValueGreater? In an array with multiple AvgWT values, #1, #2 and #3 could all be true. So are you returning an array of the values?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you can use .map() method. It will return new array with the same length includes that match checking and results. Here's the code

```js
const arry = [{"TimeSlot":"8:00 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":12152},{"TimeSlot":"8:15 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":13942},{"TimeSlot":"8:30 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"8:45 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"9:00 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"9:15 am","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"6:30 pm","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"6:45 pm","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0},{"TimeSlot":"7:00 pm","AssistedC":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWT":0}];

function checkIfMatchCondition({ AvgWT: value }) {
  if(value < 20000 && value > 15000)
    return 50
  else if(value < 15000 && value > 10000)
    return 100
  else if(value < 10000 && value > 5000)
    return 150
  return 0
}

const res = arry.map(checkIfMatchCondition);
console.log(res)
```

it can be improved by including index, or the whole object with additional property, but not enough details in the original post.

Comment: Maybe reduce would be better to get rid of the `0` entries.

Comment: it's not mentioned if result length should be same as original or not

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop.

Try running the snippet below to see if the output is what you expected, because I made a few assumptions that weren't completely clear from your question:

1. Did you want to return a single value or a whole array? My code returns an array of the same length as `arry`, with the output values stored in it.
2. What did you want it to return when `AvgWT` was outside the ranges you stated? My code returns 0 for these.

I would be happy to amend the code if I misunderstood anything!

```js
function isArrayValueGreater(arry) {

  var returnValue = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
    var element = arry[i]["AvgWT"];

    if (15000 < element && element < 20000) {
      returnValue.push(50);
    } else if (10000 < element && element < 15000) {
      returnValue.push(100);
    } else if (5000 < element && element < 10000) {
      returnValue.push(150);
    } else {
      returnValue.push(0);
    }
  }

  return returnValue;
}



var arry = [{
  "TimeSlot": "8:00 am",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 12152
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "8:15 am",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 13942
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "8:30 am",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 0
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "8:45 am",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 0
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "9:00 am",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 0
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "9:15 am",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 0
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "6:30 pm",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 0
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "6:45 pm",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 0
}, {
  "TimeSlot": "7:00 pm",
  "AssistedC": 0,
  "Abandons": 0,
  "AvgWT": 0
}];

console.log(isArrayValueGreater(arry))
```

Comment: This returns value for all the element, I just need, If any of array element `15000 < element < 20000` then need output as 50, element `15000 < element < 20000` then need output as 100, most greatest value between range value as output